# Square of an octal number

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

How to find the square of an octal number.

For example what will be the square of $23$.

It will not be $529$ because octal number system does not have digit $7$.

Comment: My guess is that you meant the octal number system does not have digit $9$.

Comment: $[23]_8=2\cdot 8^1+3\cdot 8^0=19$. Now convert $19^2=361$ back to octal.

Comment: Octal numbers have digits 0 to 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}23^2&=(20+3)^2\\&=20^2+2\times20\times3+3^2\\&=400+140+11\\&=551.\end{align}

Comment: Beat me to almost exactly the same ... noting $8_{10}=10_{8}; 9_{10}=11_8$

Comment: And that $12_{10}=14_8$.